# If open a file from my personal computer using Ctrl O in Google Chrome browser, what happens to the file? Is it now public where anyone can find it?

Tags: google-chrome

If I open a file from my personal computer using Ctrl O in Google Chrome browser, what happens to the file? Is it now public where anyone can find it? Have I just put it on the internet?

Answer (score 1):

No, the browser literally just reads the file locally, in the same way as other desktop apps do.

(However, that applies to the browser itself. If you press Ctrl+O while having certain webapps opened, they might intercept Ctrl+O for their own purposes and show a file selection dialog which can indeed upload the file to that webapp's server.)